# OpenSearch searching on (escaped) double quote returns 0 results

Tags: opensearch

We're trying to build a search engine using OpenSearch. Some of our documents contain double quotes in their indexed fields. These must be findable, even when you search for only '"'.

I know double quotes are one of the reserved chars, so I am already escaping them.

However OpenSearch will not return any results when I query for `"\""`.

My query looks as following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\""
    }
  }
}
```

Which results in
`Failed to parse query [\"]`
`Cannot parse '\"': Lexical error at line 1, column 2.  Encountered: <EOF> after : \"\""`

I can imagine the query fails when I see that the first double quote is escaped, but I have no idea how I can avoid OpenSearch doing this.

When I build op my query in NodeJS I noticed a third backslash:
`query: query.replace(/([/:*"])/g, '\\$1')` results in `"query": "\\\""`. This will prevent OpenSearch from throwing errors, but still I have no search results.

So my question is: How should I correctly write the query to find results searching on double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

> The reserved characters are: + - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? :
> \ /
>
> Failing to escape these special characters correctly could lead to a
> syntax error which prevents your query from running.

As you mentioned escaping both `\` and `"` is working fine.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\\\""
    }
  }
}
```

And if you want to search for quote `"` you should add `*` wildcard into the query like the following.

```
POST test_double_quote/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": "1" } }
{ "field": "test \" " }

GET test_double_quote/_search


GET test_double_quote/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*\\\"*"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]